How to use var in var declaration in CSS?
I noticed an unexpected problem that strange things happen when using a variable in a CSS variable declaration, the CSS itself doesn't seem to forbid it, but I can't seem to get it to work. Please suggest possible ways to solve the problem.
I'm use NextJS 14, SCSS and my flow looking like this:
const font = localFont({ ...some code..., variable: '--font-BaiJamjuree', });
<body className={font.variable}>
//
</body>


In global.css I made this:
body {
    font-family: var(--font-BaiJamjuree);
}

I'm trying this: --font-h3: 700 24px/32px var(--font-BaiJamjuree); and using like this
p{
    font: var(--font-body);
  }

the browser gives me this error:

--font-h3 is not defined

If I put __font_f1f493 in a variable, everything works, but I don't think this is good practice. Also tried insert SASS variable but was unsuccessful
$font: var(--font-BaiJamjuree);
--font-body: 400 16px/24px $font;


There's a little missing context from your code examples.
Where are you writing css variable declarations?
In scss, you can place them anywhere. But these are only available before the preprocessing. So to use them in the browser you'd have to follow the rule below.
But in css, you need them inside of a selector.
It's common to see that done under :root. This way it will be accessible to the entire document.


:root {
  --first-color: #e680a6;
  --second-color: #ffeb00;
  --degrees: 45deg;
  --gradient: var(--degrees), var(--first-color), var(--second-color);
  --x: linear-gradient(var(--gradient));
}

div {
  background: var(--x);
  
  
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
<div>
  Styled with a bunch of nested variables.
</div>



